# How do I resolve the error "no module in the root" when using a module in Rust 2018?

Tags: module, rust, rust-2018

I'm working on a project that is utilizing some local modules in folders under `src/`. I'm currently using Rust 2018 edition and one of the major changes for that is the [handling of imports/`use` statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html).

My module code is all working correctly, but as I started to pull it together to be used for the project as a whole I started getting this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::lexer`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use crate::lexer;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `lexer` in the root
```

Currently, my code is set up like this:

```
src/
 | main.rs
 | lexer/
    | mod.rs
    | lexer.rs
```

**lexer/lexer.rs**

```
pub fn lex_stuff() -> Vec<String> { vec![String::new("test")] }
```

**lexer/mod.rs**

```
pub mod lexer;
```

**main.rs**

```
use crate::lexer;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    lexer::lexer::lex_stuff();
}
```

I've attempted to resolve this by changing the statement to `use lexer` as well as `use self::lexer` and adding `extern crate lexer` (which obviously doesn't work, but what the heck, figured I'd try it). However, none of these have worked.

What can I do to resolve the `no 'lexer' in the root` error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You **still** need to declare that *main.rs* contains a module:

```rust
mod lexer; // This, not `use`    

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    lexer::lexer::lex_stuff();
}
```

Please take the time to re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), specifically the section about [Separating Modules into Different Files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html#separating-modules-into-different-files).

Comment: I eventually figured this out, hadn't had time yet to come back and create an answer explaining that. I misunderstood the linked posted in the previous answer and thought that had been replaced by `use crate::...`

Comment: WHY IS THIS REQUIRED WHEN IM ONLY USING THIS IN IN A LIB.RS?

Answer (score 4):

You need to move `mod.rs` to `lexer.rs`:

```
src/
 | main.rs
 | lexer.rs
 | lexer/
    | lexer.rs
    | tokens.rs
```

This change is described [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#no-more-modrs).

Comment: I did that, keeping the contents of `lexer.rs` (previously `lexer/mod.rs`) the same, but I'm still getting that same error.

Answer (score 3):

What most beginners (aka me perpetually) want to do is move some functions from one file like `lib.rs` into a file named `submod.rs` and access the functions in it as `submod::myfunc`. The answer that inspired me to write this suggests `lexer::lexer::lex_stuff()` which is slightly infuriating. We should never see a name twice for no serious reason. And adding another name, as the book does with `hosting` isn't helpful since naming is a hard problem in CS.

So hence, here's how to make a crepe instead of a stack of crepes (using the example from the book):

### lib.rs

```rust
mod front_of_house;
pub use crate::front_of_house::hosting;
pub fn eat_at_restaurant() {
    front_of_house::seating_capacity();
    hosting::add_to_waitlist();
}
```

### front_of_house.rs (or optionally front_of_house/mod.rs)

```rust
pub fn seating_capacity() {}

pub mod hosting {
    pub fn add_to_waitlist() {}
}
```

Now if you add a `pub fn put_up_chairs() {}` to `lib.rs` and decide, wait a minute, that belongs in `front_of_house` (but not `hosting`), you can simply move the function over to `front_of_house.rs` and refer to it in `lib.rs` as `front_of_house::put_up_chairs()`. Simple..? I hope? I'm writing to myself in the future when I forget this and find this answer again, not you gentle reader.

Note everything gets more exciting when the `pub` keyword is gone or altered, at which point maybe you should reread the book. ;)

Also one more thing, adding `pub use front_of_house;` after the `mod front_of_house` is an error, because you already have declared the module.  If you do cargo gives a loud answer (because it assumes you know what you're doing, if you're like me and program computers by bashing rocks together, you don't)

```
error[E0255]: the name `front_of_house` is defined multiple times
 --> src/lib.rs:2:9
  |
1 | mod front_of_house;
  | ------------------- previous definition of the module `front_of_house` here
2 | pub use crate::front_of_house;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `front_of_house` reimported here
  |
  = note: `front_of_house` must be defined only once in the type namespace of this module
help: you can use `as` to change the binding name of the import
  |
2 | pub use crate::front_of_house as other_front_of_house;
  |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error[E0365]: `front_of_house` is only public within the crate, and cannot be re-exported outside
 --> src/lib.rs:2:9
  |
2 | pub use crate::front_of_house;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ re-export of crate public `front_of_house`
  |
  = note: consider declaring type or module `front_of_house` with `pub`
```

If you made the above mistake of 'double using' it's ok, it's a little odd that the `mod` keyword also gives you a `use` for free. But it does and we should be thankful for it. :)

#### Motivation

In over a decade I've never written an answer on SO. But I've hit this question so many times and been so absolutely twisted in knots by the "Please take the time to re-read" answer by beloved rust wiz @Shepmaster that I'm writing an answer.  The Rust Book example is like a recipe for baking a crepe cake before showing you how to make a single crepe, at least as of the 2nd edition.